# Ortho-rectification of Aerial Image

Tags: raster, imagery, aerial-photography, orthorectification

I took an aerial image of our farm using RC quadcopter. How am I going to orthorectify this image? Please can you help me with detailed instructions/methods involving the process.

Comment: Do you have any access to GIS/imagery software?

Comment: Yes. Erdas, QGIS and arcGIS 10.1.

Comment: Look at [spatial adjustments](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_spatial_adjustment/001t000000t5000000/) and [georeferencing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Fundamentals_for_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/) in ArcMap.

Comment: But I don't think georeferencing alone would produce an orthorectified image?

Comment: You can only georeference an image with an image alone. Elevation control points are required to accurately orthorectify an image.  To "stretch" the image over the earth's surface, "rubber-sheeting" and georeferencing are the next best thing.

Comment: I have the Elevation control points. How can I use them to orthorectify?

Comment: This document gives an example about what you need (image, sensor model, dem) and how they are used in ERDAS http://www.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/DigitalGlobe_RPC_in_ERDAS_IMAGINE.pdf. This is about an open source altertive OSSIM http://download.osgeo.org/ossim/docs/pdfs/OSSIMOrthos.pdf.

Comment: It will be useful if you can edit your question to include all the clarifications that you are supplying in response to requests as comments.  Some potential answerers only look at the question itself because they do not have time to read the comments.